# How to make icon the same size as text in Android?

Tags: android, textview, icons

I have TextView with some text and ImageView with some icon. I aligned them by baseline:

```
android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/penny"
```

TextView has some text size, but I can't guess the height of ImageView so that the text (not TextView) and the icon are the same height, they are always slightly different. How I can fix it?[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ... >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/text"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set top and bottom of image view to top and bottom of textView respectively with height of imageView as `0dp` and scaleType as fitXY.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, the height of the text is less than the height of TextView. The suggested way makes the icon height equal to TextView, but much larger than the text height. This is not the result I'm expecting. In addition, the icon is greatly stretched, I would like to keep the proportions.

Comment: can you share the whole layout file. As per your requirement of ImageView having same height  for TextView should be achieved by above solution and if you don't want image to stretch use scaleType as `center`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one it might be work for you.

Make Linear layout `horizontal` with `height` as `wrap_content`,
Take Textview with your required text size. Take image view with `height` as `match_parent` and `width` as `wrap_content`.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Demo Text"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_30sdp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_app_logo" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**And for ConstraintLayout layout yu can try this as below.**

set `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDemoText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Demo Text"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_35sdp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvDemoText"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvDemoText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvDemoText"
            android:src="@drawable/material_drawer_ico_menu_down" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Text height is less than TextView height. I need text (not TextView) and icon to be the same height

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sp` unit for your image dimensions, so the image will always scale relative to the users system font size settings.